# VS 2010 automatic rebuild project after modification non .cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, build

In my C# project(WPF), I have a XML file, and I need to modify this file very often, because it is metadata for my application. After modifying this file, I pressed F5 for debugging my app, but the project would not rebuild, and I got an old version of this file in the debug folder. I need to force a rebuild of the project every time after modifying the XML file.

Can i tune VS 2010 to automatically rebuild the project after modifying the XML file?

Xml file properties in VS: `Build Action=Content`, `Copy to Output Directory=Always`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open the "Tools" menu, and click "Options".

2) Expand "Projects and Solutions".

3) Click on "Build and Run" tab.

4) In the "On Run, when projects are out of date" dropdown, select "Always build".